# Skip List implementation terminated without initialization

Tags: c, data-structures, skip-lists

I am trying to implement skip list with insertion and search operation. I am unable to spot a mistake why the program is not working properly even after using `-Wall -Wextra` options and eliminating all the warnings and errors.

The program is not even able to initialize the skip list. I have tried hours. Please help me. My implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define Malloc(n, type) (type *)malloc((unsigned)((n) * sizeof(type)))
#define Realloc(ptr, n, type) (type *)realloc(ptr, (n) * sizeof(type))

typedef struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *down;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    int level;
    struct Node *header;
} skiplist;

static int coin_flip()
{
    /*
    This function simulates a coin flip.

    arg: void
    return: a number from the set {0,1}
    */
    srand(time(NULL));
    return (rand() % 2);
}

static int level()
{
    /*
    This function takes the coin flip and decides the level of the node with each
    level having a probability of 0.25.

    arg: void
    return: a number from the set {1,2,3, 4}
    */
    int level = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (coin_flip())
        {
            level++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return level;
}

void skip_list_init(skiplist *);

Node *Traverse_Express(Node *, int);

Node *skip_list_search(skiplist *, int);

void insert_level(Node *, int, int, int);

void skip_list_insert(skiplist *, int);

void skip_print(skiplist *);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int)rand();
    }
    printf("The array is initialised\n");
    skiplist *list = NULL;
    skip_list_init(list);
    printf("The Skip list is initialised\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        skip_list_insert(list, arr[i]);
        printf("The %d element is initialised with key: %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    printf("The skip list is:\n");
    skip_print(list);
    return 0;
}

void skip_print(skiplist *list)
{
    /*
    The function prints the skip list level-wise.

    arg: list
    return: none
    */
    Node *temp = list->header;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = list->level; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printf("The Keys at level %d:\n", i);
        while (NULL != temp->next)
        {
            printf("%d ->", temp->key);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", temp->key);
        int dummy = count;
        temp = list->header;
        while (dummy)
        {
            temp = temp->down;
        }
        count++;
    }
}

void skip_list_init(skiplist *list)
{
    /*
    This function creates the first node in the skip list with key value
    to be negative infinity and level of the list =1.

    arg: It takes a list by reference
    return: None
    */
    Node *head = Malloc(1, Node);
    list->level = 1;
    list->header = head;
    head->key = INT_MIN;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->down = NULL;
}

Node *skip_list_search(skiplist *list, int key)
{
    /*
    1. The function returns the previous pointer to the required node.
    2. next_is_req is returned because only one more step is required in case of
       sucessful or unsucessful search.
    3. In case of deletion, the previous node is required for linkage.

    arg: A skip list of type skiplist, and a key of type int.
    return: A previous node (next_is_req) to the required node with or
            without key.
    */

    int level = list->level; // Number of levels already present in the list
    Node *next_is_req = NULL, *curr = list->header;
    for (; level > 0; level--)
    {
        if ((curr->key == key) && (INT_MIN != curr->key || INT_MAX != curr->key))
        {
            return next_is_req;
        }
        while ((key > curr->key) && (NULL != curr->next))
        {
            if (key < curr->next->key)
            {
                next_is_req = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (NULL != curr->down)
        {
            next_is_req = curr;
            curr = curr->down;
        }
    }
    return next_is_req;
}

Node *Traverse_Express(Node *temp, int key)
{
    while (key > temp->key && NULL != temp->next)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}

void insert_level(Node *nod, int key, int lev, int list_lev)
{
    /*
    Inserting the key till the required level

    arg:
        nod: a pointer to the exsiting skip list
        key: key to be inserted
        lev: the level of the key
        list_lev: the number of levels in the given skiplist

    return: None
    */
    Node *temp1 = nod, *temp3 = NULL;
    // Procedure to cut-off the extra levels in the list if any
    if (lev < list_lev)
    {
        for (int i = list_lev - lev; i > 0; i--)
        {
            temp1 = Traverse_Express(temp1, key);
            temp1 = temp1->down;
        }
    }
    // Procedure to insert from the required level till level 1
    for (int i = 0; i < lev; i++)
    {
        Node *temp2 = Malloc(1, Node);
        temp2->key = key;
        temp2->next = NULL;
        temp2->down = NULL;
        temp1 = Traverse_Express(temp1, key);
        if (NULL == temp1->next)
        {
            temp1->next = temp2;
        }
        else
        {
            temp2->next = temp1->next;
            temp1->next = temp2;
        }
        if (i > 0)
        {
            temp3->down = temp2;
        }
        temp1 = temp1->down;
        temp3 = temp2;
    }
}

void skip_list_insert(skiplist *list, int key)
{
    /*
    This function finds the key value and if already present, then returns back
    else it inserts the key at its right place.



    arg: a skilplist by reference and a key
    return: None
    */
    Node *next_req = skip_list_search(list, key);
    if (key == next_req->next->key)
    {
        printf("Key %d is already present in skip list", key);
        return;
    }
    Node *temp1 = list->header;
    int list_lev = list->level;
    int lev = level();
    Node *temp2 = NULL;
    // creating a skip list if level returned is greater than existing one.
    if (lev > list->level)
    {
        for (int i = lev - list_lev; i > 0; i--)
        {
            skip_list_init(list);
            Node *inser = Malloc(1, Node);
            inser->key = key;
            list->header->next = inser;
            Node *temp3 = list->header;
            while (temp2)
            {
                temp3->down = temp2;
                temp3 = temp3->next;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
            temp2 = list->header;
            list = NULL;
        }
        list->header = temp2;
        while (NULL != temp2->down)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->down;
        }
    }
    // Inserting the node till the min(list_lev, level())
    if (list_lev > lev)
    {
        insert_level(temp1, key, lev, list_lev);
    }
    else
    {
        insert_level(temp1, key, list_lev, list_lev);
    }
    // Zipping Procedure only if level()>list_lev
    if (lev > list_lev)
    {
        temp2 = list->header;
        while (NULL != temp2->down)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->down;
        }
        temp2->down = temp1;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        while (temp1->key != key)
        {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp2->down = temp1;
        list->level = lev;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it throw any errors? What happens?

Comment: @kiner_shah It Successfully compiles without any errors or warning as I am using ```-Wall -Wextra``` options to it. In the main function, the array of random numbers is Initialized successfully. But when I call the function ```skip_list_init```, it exits.

Comment: Exits with what exit code? Non-zero exit code?

Comment: @kiner_shah It exists normally (from cmd, when i execute ```c:/>./a.out```  It prints ```The array is initialised``` and after some wait, I see ```C:/>```) . Is there any way to see what exit code the program throws?

Comment: Ohk, I know why it suddenly exits. In `skip_list_init` you access `list` without checking whether it's `NULL` - that leads to Segmentation Fault (or Access violation).

Comment: @kiner_shah How do I resolve it?

Comment: Allocate memory to `list` and it should at least proceed further.

Comment: So the return type would also change for the function, right?

Comment: Why change function signature? You should first try allocating the list with some memory and check how much progress happens. If something doesn't work as expected then figure out what could be going wrong.